# So what is the simplest approach for Caching in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

The app is a simple news reader which shows WordPress posts, nothing fancy, not using a BLOC, inherited Widget, Firebase.
I want it to show the cached data(which is the latest 10 posts) even when the user is offline.

So if the user is offline show Cached data; or somehow default data is cached data.

get the firstPost[Id] from WP REST API
If the cached Json file contains Post[id] then show cached data;
Else getPosts(); and show loading indicator. also please update the local JSON file.

code to get JSON data:

```
// Function to fetch list of posts
 Future<String> getPosts() async {
 var res = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(apiUrl + "posts?_embed&per_page=10"), //TODO make it unlimited
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

setState(() {
  var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

  posts = resBody;
});

return "Success!";
}
```

the future to get posts and shows loading indicator :

```
  body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: getPosts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListViewPosts(posts: snapshot.data)
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    ),
```

Comment: `LruMap` maybe?

Comment: I know you stated NO FIREBASE in the question, but you know that it already provides that, right? You could fetch the posts, save it in the firebase database, and offline use will be available. (tbc)

Comment: I have made [this search and found](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=cache+flutter) some interesting packages. [This one](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cs_cache) looks like it's exactly what you looking for, and [this one](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cache_manager) would be maybe something more appropriate to a mobile environment if you have large objects.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple time-based cache doesn't require much code.

This might help you out. It uses `ScopedModel`, but it could just as easily be a simple class, although you'd have to either remove the `notifyListeners()` call or replace it with your own mechanism if you want the model to trigger a refresh of the UI.

```
class MyModel extends Model{
    Duration _cacheValidDuration;
    DateTime _lastFetchTime;
    List<MyRecord> _allRecords;



    MyModel(){
        _cacheValidDuration = Duration(minutes: 30);
        _lastFetchTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);
        _allRecords = [];
    }



    /// Refreshes all records from the API, replacing the ones that are in the cache.
    /// Notifies listeners if notifyListeners is true.
    Future<void> refreshAllRecords(bool notifyListeners) async{
        _allRecords = await MyApi.getAllRecords(); // This makes the actual HTTP request
        _lastFetchTime = DateTime.now();
        if( notifyListeners ) this.notifyListeners();
    }


    /// If the cache time has expired, or forceRefresh is true, records are refreshed from the API before being returned.
    /// Otherwise the cached records are returned.
    Future<List<MyRecord>> getAllRecords({bool forceRefresh = false}) async{
        bool shouldRefreshFromApi = (null == _allRecords || _allRecords.isEmpty || null == _lastFetchTime || _lastFetchTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(_cacheValidDuration)) || forceRefresh);

        if( shouldRefreshFromApi )
           await refreshAllRecords(false);

        return _allRecords;
    }
}
```

To get data from `MyModel`, the UI simply calls `getAllRecords()`. This will either fetch the records from memory (i.e. from `_allRecords`) or trigger a refresh which would make a HTTP call and update the records. The cached data automatically expires after 30 minutes, and if you want to force a refresh (for example if the user explicitly taps a refresh button), you can pass `forceRefresh: true`.

Comment: good guy, simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

After experiencing many solutions for caching, here is what I’ve learned sorted by complexity:

1- using shared preferences
2- using hive db
3- using firestore offline service
4- using sqflite

Comment: 1 being most complex or least?

Comment: Can you please recommend/share useful links to achieve this using shared prefrences.

Comment: I really suggest using HiveDB.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of caching is by using hive a No-SQL database it is faster to retrieve documents and is easy to use. And when users come online just refresh the data in hive

For more details check:https://github.com/shashiben/Anime-details to know how to cache using hive