# Caching and Supplying Cached Data to StreamBuilder Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am currently using `StreamBuilder` to fetch data from `Cloud Firestore` and everything works well but I am having issues because when I fetch the data from the database, I have to perform some async actions on the data to filter the data and each time a user goes to a different page and back to the home page, the page refreshes itself doing performing the async actions that are not needed.

The async function takes a little bit of time and so I am trying to use a cache to store the data loaded in the beginning and only reload the data when you refresh. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664901/10530378) that shows an example of simple caching.

This is my implementation

```
class FetchObjects {


  Duration _cacheValidDuration;
  DateTime _lastFetchTime;

  List<DataModel> currentData = [];

  FetchObject() {
    _cacheValidDuration = Duration(minutes: 30);
    _lastFetchTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);

    fetchtheData();
  }

  Future<void> refereshData() async {
    await getFromDataBase();
  }

  Future<List<DataModel>> fetchtheData({bool forceRefresh = false}) async {
    bool shouldRefreshFromApi = (null == currentData ||
        currentData.isEmpty ||
        null == _lastFetchTime ||
        _lastFetchTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(_cacheValidDuration)) ||
        forceRefresh);

    if (shouldRefreshFromApi) {
      await refereshData();
    }

    return currentData;
  }

  void getDataFromDataBase() async {
    await Firestore.instance...getDocuments()
        .then((onValue) {
      filterData(onValue.documents);
    });
  }

  void filterData(List potentialData) async {
    for (DocumentSnapshot docs in potentialData) {


       String criteria = perfomAsyncOperation(doc);

        if (if passes Creteria) {
          Model newModel = new Model.from(docs);
            this.currentData.add(newModel);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am now trying to use the result from this class in a `StreamBuilder` as follows:

```
  @override
  void initState() {

    backEndCall = new FetchObjects();
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        body: StreamBuilder<List<Model>>(
            stream: Stream.fromFuture(backEndCall.fetchtheData()),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<model>> snapshot) {
                  print(" the data is "+snapshot.data.toString());
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(snapshot.error);
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("Error");
              }

              if (!snapshot.hasData &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting &&
                  snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "no data",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                return Container(
                  // color: Colors.pink,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "There is data",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                );


              } else {
                print(snapshot.connectionState);
                return Container(
                    child: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }
```

So far, I am not having any luck retrieving the data from the FetchObjects class. It gets the data fine but I cannot get it in the StreamBuilder. Any ideas on a different implementation or a fix to this implementation?

Comment: use `Stream#asyncMap` for example

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a whole different approach. 
I made sure that the page is kept alive when you navigated to a new page. I did this by extending the class with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and overriding

```
@override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

Example

```
class SampleClassState extends State<SampleClass> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

}
```

See [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19116). This way, the page is only reloaded when you refresh.

Comment: It sounds like a hack. If you want to cache data you shouldn't have to cache the UI but only the data. It sounds like you need a state management solution, like [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).