# Is there a way to Cache Cards in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In a page of my app I need to scroll hundreds of cards with images Texts and tags

If inside the cards there are only images it scrolls very fast and smooth, probably because flutter cache images

But if I use Texts and Tags the scrolling is not smooth

Is it possible to use some kind of cache for cards?

Comment: are you using listview builder?

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out yourself, you can use `FutureBuilder` class, but if you are interested in actually caching your data, then consider a simple approach [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459669/so-what-is-the-simplest-approach-for-caching-in-flutter).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used FutureBuilder Widget to construct Tags and images of my cards

In this way the scrolling is smooth and when data arrive complete the construction of the cards

[FutureBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)